# In The Heights trailer: "Dreamers" or "DREAMers"?

Tags: dialogue, trailers, in-the-heights

In the [In The Heights trailer](https://youtu.be/U0CL-ZSuCrQ?t=91)
 released this week, a character says the line "they're talking about kicking out all the dreamers." ([1:31](https://youtu.be/U0CL-ZSuCrQ?t=91)) Is this a generic reference to the characters in the movie who have big dreams, or is it specifically referring to the [DREAMers movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DREAM_Act#DREAMers_movement)?

(Hoping for a more authoritative source than the YouTube captions, which have "dreamers" lowercased.)